# Is this C BNF grammar incomplete?

Tags: c, grammar, bnf

I often see this [C grammar](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) in books. However it seems `<identifier>` is never declared.

Am I missing something or is this grammar incomplete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't speak for whether the grammar is complete, but `<identifier>` is a token (i.e. a terminal), in the same way as e.g. `<string>` and many others are.

Tokens are not defined in the grammar itself but rather in a lexer specification.

The lexer is a component of most parser systems, which reads the raw input and turns it into a stream of higher level tokens (a.k.a. lexemes) that the parser then consumes.

Comment: Yeah but C99, specifies what is an identifier. It must start with a non-numeric value, ... So this should be part of the grammer, not the lexer right?

Comment: No, a lexer can make that determination, though the borderline between lexer and grammar is fluid. [Here's someone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193787/simple-c99-lexer) (not me) working on a sample lexer for C99 that you may be able to draw some inspiration from.

Comment: @nowox It's part of the lexical grammar, which is its own separate thing.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard defines two grammars: The lexical grammar and the "Phrase structure grammar". In the C99 standard you can find these in annexes A.1 and A.2 respectively.

The lexical grammar is a regular grammar that derives a single token. Its terminals are individual characters. Source code can be processed into a sequence of tokens by deriving words from the lexical grammar repeatedly.

The phrase structure grammar is a CFG (with some additional non-context free restrictions added in plain English) whose terminals are the lexical elements defined in the lexical grammar (or rather the pre-processed version of them).

The grammar in your link is based on the phrase structure grammar and does not include the lexical grammar. As such it does not contain the rules for identifiers and other tokens, but simply uses them as terminals.